# Adding a product to favourite products page in not working CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm working on a project on CodeIgniter and now I'm trying to make a button so a user can add a product to his favourites. So what I want is that when a logged in user goes to a product detail page, and clicks on the button 'add to favourites' it must copy the product and show on the new view page(cadeaupagina_ontvangen view page). And the next time the same user logges in, the same product must be on that view page. I also made a new row in my products table thats called 'ontvangen_cadeaus' which means favourite products.

So this is the button 'add to favourites' from the product details page:

```
  <a href="<?php echo base_url() . 'Product/cadeaupagina_ontvangen/'.$product_id.'/'. $user_id;?>"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Ik wil dit cadeau!</button></a>
```

The details function in Product.php controller:

```
public function details($product_id)
  {
    $this->load->library('session');
    //load the Product_model
    $this->load->model('Product_model');
    //call function getdata in de Product_model
    $data['userdetail_list'] = $this->Product_model->getdata();
  //  $this->session->set_userdata("product_id", $product_id);
    $data['user_id'] = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $data['product_id'] = $this->session->userdata('product_id');

    //get product details
    $data['product'] = $this->Product_model->get_product_details($product_id);
    $data['products'] = $this->Product_model->selectProducts();

    //laad view
    $data['main_content'] = 'details';
    $this->load->view('details',$data); 
  }
```

The cadeaupagina_ontvangen function in Product.php controller:

```
public function cadeaupagina_ontvangen($product_id='',$user_id='') { 
  $this->load->model('Product_model'); 
  //call function getdata in de Product_model 
  $data['userdetail_list'] = $this->Product_model->getdata(); 

  //get ontvangen cadeaus
  if(!empty($product_id)&& !empty($user_id)){ 
  $data['products'] = $this->Product_model->get_related_product($product_id,$user_id); 
  } 

  //laad view 
  $data['main_content'] = 'ontvangen_cadeaus'; 
  $this->load->view('cadeaupagina_ontvanger',$data); 
  }
```

The get related products function in Product_model.php :

```
 function get_related_product($product_id='',$user_id=''){ 
     if(!empty($product_id)&&!empty($user_id)){ 
     $this->db->select('*'); 
     $this->db->from('products'); 
     $this->db->where('product_id', $product_id); 
     $this->db->where('ontvangen_cadeaus', $user_id); 
     $query = $this->db->get(); 
     $result = $query->row_array(); 
     if ($result->num_rows()) { 
     return $result->row(); 
     } else { 
     $insert_data = array('ontvangen_cadeaus'=> $user_id); 
     $this->db->where('product_id', $product_id); 
     $this->db->update('products ', $data); 
  } 
    } 
      }
```

getdata function in Product_model:

```
public function getdata($userid='') 
   { 
  $this->db->select('*'); 
  $this->db->from('users'); 
  $this->db->join('products','products.user_id = users.user_id'); 
  if(!empty($userid)){ 
  $this->db->where('users.user_id', $userid); 
  } 
  $query = $this->db->get(); 
  if($query->num_rows()>0) 
  { 
  return $query->result_array(); 
  } 
  }
```

The view page where the button on the details page is linking to (cadeaupagina_ontvangen view page):

```
    <?php foreach($products as $product) { ?>

    <div class="main-gifts">

          <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/Product/details/<?php echo $product["product_id"]; ?>">
          <img id="fotos" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>upload/<?php echo $product["product_foto_thumb"]; ?>">
        </a>
        <div class="products_discription">
        <h3><?php echo $product["product_naam"]; ?></h3>

        <div class="ophaal_plaats">
        <p>Plaats: <?php  echo $product["ophaal_plaats"]; ?></p>
        </div>

        <div class="aangeboden_door">
         <p> <?php  /** Foreach loop om de voornaam van de eigenaar van het product te displayen **/
        foreach($userdetail_list as $row)
                        {
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $row['voornaam'];?></td>
                         </tr>
       <?php } ?></p>
              </div>
              <div class="status">
         <p> Status:</p>
              </div>
          </div>
            <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/KdGwController/details_bewerken/<?php echo $product["product_id"]; ?>"><input type="button" class="btn btn-default cb" value="Cadeau bewerken"></input> </a>

        </div>
<?php } ?>
```

So when I click on the button from the detail page to the new view page (cadeaupagina_ontvangen view page) the product is not added to that page and I'm getting these errors:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: products

Filename: views/cadeaupagina_ontvanger.php

Line Number: 12

Backtrace:

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/views/cadeaupagina_ontvanger.php
Line: 12
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/controllers/Product.php
Line: 52
Function: view

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: views/cadeaupagina_ontvanger.php

Line Number: 12

Backtrace:

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/views/cadeaupagina_ontvanger.php
Line: 12
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/controllers/Product.php
Line: 52
Function: view

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Can anyone notice what and which file I'm doing wrong?
I posted all the information that belongs to the function because I don't know in which file I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: You logic is very flawed. First off, `user_id` should always be not empty because if it isn't the user wouldn't be logged in, right? Secondly, you want to get a related project or projects? Because if you are doing a foreach loop on projects in your view that means that you expect more than one?? Yet you are only returning a single row??

Comment: Thirdly, if you are doing `num_rows()` which is great! but you don't return false if nothing is found. This is a surefired way of getting notices!

Answer (score 0):

Well .. do check in the logs / url that gets generated on the link whether it is having product_id / user_id being set because in the code - there is a condition / check

`if(!empty($product_id)&& !empty($user_id)){`

Both of the condition needs to be fulfilled before it can proceed further and fetch products. One - Suggestion, don't pass the user_id as parameter. It can create easy hackable scenario for any user - they may specify any other users id too. That will start creating malfunctioning of the application. Instead pick the user_id from the session.

Comment: So can u show me what to do instead of passing the user_id as a parameter? And when I click on the button this happens with the link: Product/cadeaupagina_ontvangen//9 . so only the user_id is in the link?

Comment: well if not mistaken - the user_id can be retrieved from session as the user have logged in. Currently what is happening in the url as observed - the product_id is not getting passed on. To resolve the issue at current stage - just make sure you pass on the product_id along with the URL.

As for user_id, try to retrieve and use the same from session

Comment: But thats what I tried to do right? like this: 'Product/cadeaupagina_ontvangen/'.$product_id.'/'. $user_id;?>

Comment: Well, the $data variable that you sending in to the details page (where you are generating the link), are you passing any product_id ... like $data['product_id'] = someproductid?


If not, then it wont work up. If you are passing in just $data['product'] = $product as a whole object, then you should pick the ID something like $product['id']

Comment: Ah okay thanks, I now have it like this: 'Product/cadeaupagina_ontvangen/'.$product['product_id'].'/'. $user_id;?> and also it the url it says : Product/cadeaupagina_ontvangen/100/9 . So product_id=100 and user_id= 9. So I guess that part is correct, but I do get an error on the page, its this error: Message: Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object

Filename: models/Product_model.php and its this line thats wrong in my get_related_product model function: if ($result->num_rows()) {   Do you know why I get this error?

Comment: can you paste in the code? There is a possible that $result might not be an proper object that you may be getting in or quite possible there are no records in the database matching the criteria.

Comment: You can check my get related products function  in my question. Can you check if its good working code?

Comment: Could you find mistakes in my model function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159786/discussion-between-blakdronzer-and-learningprogrammingphp44).

Answer (score 0):

I have a few concerns with your code I hope to address:

1. You should always return something from your models even if `num_rows()` is `==0` and if you expect a variable to be in your view you can't just skip defining it. Hence your current errors.
2. If you return an object you have to access it as one.
3. Your need to separate add functions from select functions.
4. You need to ALWAYS expect errors and user stupidity no matter what!
5. You should stop passing around the `$user_id` like it is a hot potato.

The following code assumes some things (like you want to get all user favorites not just one), change it to your liking. Please autoload your session library in the autoload section of CI. I changed a few function names for consistency and maintainability. I personally handle errors and success messages when redirecting from a controller function whose sole responsibility is CRUD-related with flash messages. I suggest you do the same as now you will account for errors. This means that you have to display the flash messages to the user, but I'll leave that up to you.

Please pay attention to the comments and understand this code may not work out of the box. I put a lot of work in to this so you will better understand good coding practices! (I was a beginner too).

```
<?php

// autoload your session! don't keep loading it in every class

class Product_controller extends blahblah
{

    public function cadeaupagina_ontvangen()
    {
        $this->load->model('Product_model');
        $data['userdetail_list'] = $this->product_model->get_data();
        // if product ID is empty we have an empty array
        $data['products'] = $this->product_model->get_favorite_products();
        $data['main_content'] = 'ontvangen_cadeaus';
        $this->load->view('cadeaupagina_ontvanger', $data);
    }

    // accessed via: product/add_favorite_project/$id
    function add_favorite_project($product_id = '')
    {
        if (empty($product_id) || $this->product_model->add_favorite_product($product_id)) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Could not add favorite product.');
        }
        redirect('product/cadeaupagina_ontvangen/'); // or wherever...
    }
}

class Product_model extends CI_Model
{

    public function get_favorite_products()
    {
        if (empty($product_id)) {
            return false;
        }
        $this->db->where('ontvangen_cadeaus', $this->session->user_id);
        $query = $this->db->get('products');
        if ($result->num_rows() == 1) {
            //return $result->row(); row() is an object not an array!
            //in any case we want to get all the results, right? result_array it is
            return $result->result_array();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Logical issue with this code, you essentially overwrite the
     * field ontvangen_cadeaus every time a user decided to add a new product
     * to their favorites. Thus, no two users can have the same favorite, this
     * doesn't seem right, you should have a seperate table for this
     * with the user_id, favorite_product, and the corresponding product_id
     */
    public function add_favorite_product($product_id)
    {
        $this->db->where('product_id', $product_id);
        return $this->db->update('products', array('ontvangen_cadeaus' => $this->session->user_id));
        /* see above comment
          $str = array('user_id' => $this->session->user_id, 'product_id' => $product_id);
          $this->db->get_where('favorite_products', $str);
          if ($query->num_rows() == 0) {
          return $this->db->insert('favorite_products', $str)
          } else {
          return true;
          }
         */
    }

    public function get_data()
    {
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->join('products', 'products.user_id = users.user_id');
        $this->db->where('users.user_id', $this->session->user_id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result_array();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

?>
<?php if($products !== false): ?>
<?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>
    <div class="main-gifts">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/product/details/<?php echo $product["product_id"]; ?>">
            <img id="fotos" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/upload/<?php echo $product["product_foto_thumb"]; ?>">
        </a>
        <div class="products_discription">
            <h3><?php echo $product["product_naam"]; ?></h3>
            <div class="ophaal_plaats">
                <p>Plaats: <?php echo $product["ophaal_plaats"]; ?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="aangeboden_door">
                <p>
                    <?php if ($userdetail_list !== false): ?>
                        <?php foreach ($userdetail_list as $row): ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $row['voornaam']; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="status">
                <p> Status:</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/KdGwController/details_bewerken/<?php echo $product["product_id"]; ?>"><input type="button" class="btn btn-default cb" value="Cadeau bewerken"></input> </a>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Please note my tone might come across harsh but I'm just trying to be a good teacher ;)

Comment: You said this: you should have a seperate table for this
     * with the user_id, favorite_product, and the corresponding product_id . I have a seperate table for user_id and product_id but the favourite product (ontvangen cadeaus) is a row in the user table

Comment: ontvangen_cadeaus is 'favourite products' in my language . So should I use this code: /* see above comment
          $str = array('user_id' => $this->session->user_id, 'product_id' => $product_id);
          $this->db->get_where('favorite_products', $str);
          if ($query->num_rows() == 0) {
          return $this->db->insert('favorite_products', $str)
          } else {
          return true;
          }
         */ and change it to ontvangen_cadeaus?

Comment: Also getting an error on this line:  if (empty($product_id)) {  in the Product.php function controller

Comment: For the error just remove the if statement. Forgot to do that. And I still don't get your database structure. What does ontvangen cadeaus row look like? And you can't store more than one favorite in a single field without serializing or something but that's a different story entirely. To be honest I think you are biting off more than you can chew and you should start with the basics of php and then going through the ci documentation in an orderly fashion otherwise your code will be riddled with errors.

Comment: Ok I don't think you fully understand what I want. Can you tell me how in CodeIgniter I can make a button on the product details page of the products . And when you click on that button the product will copy to a new view page and it will link to that view page. So now when that user goes to his 'favourite products' page he can see the product there. I just want a favourite products page for users which users can select so they can see all their favourite products on 1 view page. I just don't know how to do that. I made a new column in my users table for the favourites but that doesn't work

Comment: Like I tried to explain you can't have a single column and expect to have multiple items in that column. You should have a table for favorite projects as I explained in the code comment. Otherwise you have to serialize/unserialize a string or array of favorite project id's.

Comment: So I need to make a new table named 'favourite' products with 1 column which is user_id ?

Comment: Hello you there can you explain me how I should make this function so a user can have multiple favourites ?